# how to reach join fields with separator?

Tags: linux

how to reach join fields "a, b, f" in jointest7 and "a, b, x" in jointest8 to join both files?

```
[admin@localhost ~187]$ head jointest7 jointest8
==> jointest7 <==
1 x:b a:c
2 x:d b:e
3 x:g f:i

==> jointest8 <==
1 a:y:z
2 b:o:p
3 x:j:i
```